# Using sed to get first N characters AND last N Characters

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I have a file containing records with large amounts of data per line. 
For example:

```
:~$ cat filename
record_1 data_a data_b data_c data_d data_e 123
record_2 data_a data_b data_c data_d data_e 456
record_3 data_a data_b data_c data_d data_e 789
```

I would like to view information in the first `N` characters and the last `N` characters of each line of data in the file using `sed` and `grep` to get a specifc record for example

```
:~$ grep 'record_1' filename | [some sed command here]
record_1 123
```

Is there a `sed` command I could use or is there some other method to get this kind of result? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` you can do:

```
sed -rn '/record_1/s/(.{8}).*(.{3})$/\1 \2/p' file

record_1 123
```

In case you want to read 1st and last fields then use:

```
awk '/record_1/{print $1, $NF}' file

record_1 123
```

Comment: Explanation: Anubhava skips the `grep` with `/record_1/`. The number 8 in the `sed` command is your number N, the 3 is an alternative value for N.

Answer (score 0):

awk might be better, especially if all the records are the same length, as appears in the question.

```
    awk '{print $1 $n}' filename
```

Where n is the number of the last field. $7 contains 123, $6 contains data_e , and so on.

Comment: Corrected, you don't always need a pattern match.

Comment: Better. However, the fields are going to be concatenated, no separator.

Comment: I love those answers "use YYY" when the question is "how to use XXX". This answer is basically off-topic. It works but it's not using `sed` as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract characters based on given sizes, here is another alternative

```
$ s=8;e=3; paste <(cut -c1-$s file) <(rev file | cut -c1-$e | rev)

record_1        123
record_2        456
record_3        789
```

you specify sizes from s(tart) to e(nd).

Comment: I love those answers "use YYY" when the question is "how to use XXX". This answer is basically off-topic. It works but it's not using `sed` as requested.